# catch type dispatching time

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

There was a question that were discussing with colleagues - type dispatching of `catch` is done compile time or tun-time?
In other words - when does the system decides that particular `catch` should be invoked when an exception of that particular type is thrown.
I think it should be run-time, but I'm not sure.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The document [Technical report on C++ performance](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf) describes several techniques used by the compilers to deal with exception handling.

The latest compilers build a table that maps the exception type to the catch handler location (during the compilation phase). When the compiled program runs and a `throw` happens then a lookup on the pre-computed table is performed to find the handler location.